# Swift - Understanding when it is the last iteration in for loop over an array of integers

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, integer, iteration

I have a for loop in my Swift code that iterates over array of integers.

```
var indexes:[Int] = []
....
....
for oneInt in indexes
        {
            if (oneInt==indexes.last) {doSomethingElse(oneInt)}
                                      else {doSomething(oneInt)}
        }
```

My need is to understand when it is the last element.

Using the provided "last" value I think I have an integer, not an object.

So how can I compare the values to know I have the last?

Or should I rewrite the for loop?

Swift seems to have no traditional for loop.

Do I have to use a counter variable?

Comment: Too many questions in one (and too little research done). Read [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID121) about for loops. And while you are reading in the Swift Programming Language book also check out the section about [arrays](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID107)

Comment: It would be much easier to just drop the last element of your collection `for oneInt in indexes.dropLast()`, and doSomething to `oneInt` and then get the last element of your collection `if let last = indexes.last {` and doSomethingElse with `last`. No need to check in every iteration if the index is equal to the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use enumerated:

```
for (index, oneInt) in indexes.enumerated() {
if (index==indexes.count-1) { doSomething(oneInt) } 
                          else { doSomethingElse(oneInt) }
}
```